# c# - how to generate click event in repeater?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i want to add product when i click" add to cart "button but in repeater how can i do ?
how to generate onclick event ?

```
<div class="product">
     <div class="text">
          <h3><%#Eval("Name")%></h3>
          <p style="text-align:center;"><b> <%#Eval("qty") %></b></p>
          <p class="price">Rs.<%#Eval("Price") %></p>
          <p class="buttons">
             <button runat="server" id="b1" onclick="b1_cl" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</button>
          </p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Webform**

This will generate one button per item. At Html level id remains unique, as the repeater is concatenating an index at the end.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCreated="Repeater1_ItemCreated" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <button type="submit" runat="server" id="myButton" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart
        </button>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code behind**

Adding the handler and item index as I will need it later.

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (HtmlButton)e.Item.FindControl("myButton");
    if (button != null)
    {
        button.Attributes["index"] = e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString();
        button.ServerClick += new EventHandler(MyButton_Click);
    }
}
```

And finally the click handler:

```
protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string index = ((HtmlButton)sender).Attributes["index"];
}
```

The variable `index` tells you which item was clicked. Another options is passing the index to the handler instead of setting it as an attribute.